# RaspBMC default password for SSH

Tags: raspbmc, ssh

I installed RaspBMC and tried the default password for SSH:

- user `pi`
- passwd `rasberry`

But I'm getting access denied. Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Comment: +1 happened to me the first time I used pi...didn't take long to find the problem though!

Comment: I had wrote "raspberry" and it hadn't worked. What's wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The default password is `raspberry` ... you're leaving off the "**p**".

Comment: argh. That's what I get for late night installing. Thanks.